# Grub2 + Xen: How to solve "Can't find hypervisor information in sysfs"

Tags: ubuntu, grub2, xen

I am trying to solve the "Can't find hypervisor information in sysfs" problem when invoking "xm". I have found in some [sites](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2008795) that the solution is to rename *10_linux* into *50_linux*, however if I do this, whenever I reboot my computer, the memtest starts (so I have to reset the previous grub configuration through a live cd). I am aware that it might be a silly question, but does anyone have a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.  Googling around I came across this [forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2008795). Initially I did the same as you renaming 10_linux to 50_linux, however first time around I forgot to:

> [sudo] update-grub2

I sudo'd the command however not sure it's required. Now all is working.

Comment: The official Debian (dpkg'ish way) is described here: https://xen-orchestra.com/cant-find-hypervisor-information-in-sysfs/